# Cout from a map with std::tuple

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, tuples, maps

I have made a small map that I call `BMW`. It contains the keys `Usage` and `Diesel`, as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // initialize container
    std::map<string, std::tuple<string, string>> BMW;

    // insert elements
    BMW.insert({"Usage", {"1", "2"}});
    BMW.insert({"Disel", {"2", "3"}});

    std::cout << "Usage => " << BMW.find('Usage')->second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is to find the key `Usage` in the map and then print out the strings containing the values for `Usage`(1, 2). The code I tried with does not work and I am not able to find a good answer why here on Stackoverflow. Here is the error I get:

`error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::find(int)'|`

It would be great if I could be able to get only one of the strings, like the first one, if I want to do that.

(the strings will later be converted to int when this is appropriate, but because of technical reasons I want to read them as strings for now)

Comment: It seems far more complicated than the thing I want to do?

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: This is what I get when running it; `error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::find(int)'|`

Comment: Put that in the question. The question should contain all information necessary to answer it. You know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BMW.find('Usage')->second
//       ^     ^
```

These are **single quotes**.

Single quotes delimit `char` literals.

You wanted **double quotes**.

That's because double quotes delimit *string* literals.

---

The reason the error message says you're trying to use the non-existent `find(int)` overload, is that a `char` literal that actually has more than one character in it is a special thing called a "multi-character literal", of `int` type and implementation-defined value. You usually don't intend to use these.

---

Next, you're going to run into the problem that there is no built-in `cout` formatting for a tuple. You will have to take `BMW.find("Usage")->second` and give it to some function that prints the contents in whatever way you want.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to assign `BMW.find("Usage")->second` to a string? Like this:

`string Test;     Test.assign(BMW.find("Usage")->second);`

Comment: @KGB91 The `second` is a tuple, not a string, so no. If you need it as a string, you will have to convert it somehow (perhaps concatenating the two elements?).

Comment: Can I just get one of the values in the tuple somehow? I will later need one of the values at the time.

Comment: Aha!  `Test.assign(std::get<0>(BMW.find("Usage")->second)); std::cout << "Usage => " << Test << '\n';`

Now it works, thanks!

Comment: @KGB91 Yes, the same way you ever access elements of a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

For starters if you are using the member function `find` then you should check whether the data is indeed found.

In this expression

```
BMW.find('Usage')
```

you are using a multibyte character literal instead of a string literal. The expression must be written like

```
BMW.find( "Usage" )
```

There is no operator << for an object of the type `std::tuple`. You have to output individual data members of the tuple. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::tuple<std::string, std::string>> BMW;

    // insert elements
    BMW.insert( { "Usage", { "1", "2" } } );
    BMW.insert( { "Disel", { "2", "3" } } );

    auto it = BMW.find( "Usage" );

    if ( it != std::end( BMW ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Usage => ( " << std::get<0>( it->second ) << ", " << std::get<1>( it->second ) << " )\n";
    }        
}
```

Its output is

```
Usage => ( 1, 2 )
```